# Ошибка "Manifest merger failed"

Tags: android-studio, admob, android-manifest, androidx

Изменил название пакета "com.xxx.xxx" с помощью `Refactor > Rename` и смены названия пакета и id приложения в `manifest` и `gradle`. Успешная синхронизация, всё окей. По инструкциям [delevopers.google Get Started](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=ru#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk) и [delevopers.google Interstitial Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=ru) встроил в своё приложение рекламу, предварительно включив в `project structure` **AdMob**. Тоже никаких ошибок не выдавалось при синхронизации gradle, но стоило мне попробовать запустить приложение на физическом устройстве, как мне выдало ошибку:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-27:19 to override.
```

Если добавлять `android.useAndroidX=true` и `android.enableJetifier=true` в свойства gradle, то всё становится ещё хуже, т.к. мой `MainActivity.java` экстендит `AppCompatActivity`, который не используется при указанных выше свойствах `gradle` (android.useAndroidX=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогает при этом случае просто пересборка всего проекта (сделать заного проект, копируя всё из старого) + рефакторинг на AndroidX. Другие способов я не нашёл